# Calculation in a variable

Tags: ruby

I'm building a running pace calculator in Ruby. The script prompts for the distance of the run and then the duration of the run. I set a variable to divide the distance by time, and would like to print it to the screen:

```
puts "Pace Calculator"

puts "What is the distance in KM?"
distance = gets

puts "What is the time in minutes?"
time = gets

#this is where the error occurs
pace = "#{distance}/#{time}"

puts "Your pace is #{pace}"
```

The code doesn't seem to be working correctly. How do I do a calculation?

Comment: It is always better to mention the error log you are getting!

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to be working correctly" mean? Does it work correctly or not? If not, why? What do you expect to happen? And why? What happens instead? Why is what happens instead not the thing that should happen? Are you getting any errors? Which ones? Are you getting any warnings? Which ones? Do you have failing tests? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs, including for special cases, edge cases, corner cases, and exceptions? Can you provide a precise specification how to get from those inputs to those outputs, including special, edge, and corner cases, and exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the line you're having the error on to:

```
pace = distance.to_f / time.to_f
```

You're currently trying to do this in a string, which doesn't seem to make much sense. `to_f` converts a string (from input) to a floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

you can make something like this

```
puts "Pace Calculator"

puts "What is the distance in KM?"
distance = gets

puts "What is the time in minutes?"
time = gets


#this is where the error occurs, how do I do a calculation in a variable?
puts "#{distance}/#{time}"

pace = distance.to_f / time.to_f

puts "Your pace is #{pace}"
```